# Titanium "Creating [object TiMediaSound] in a different context than the calling function."

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am getting an error in my code when I call a sound object in a callback timer. The wav file will play exactly once, before the error is thrown. If I wrap it in a timeout function it will work everytime. Should I be coding a different way get rid of this error?

```
function InitInterval() {
timer.stop();
timer.setInterval({
    callback : IntervalMain,
    delay : 1000 //set delay in ms
});
timer.start();
};

function IntervalMain() {
has_started = true;

if (countdown === 0) {
    schedule_index++;

    setTimeout(function() {
        PlayAudio(schedule[schedule_index].sound, schedule[schedule_index].type);
    }, 500);
}

$.crono_label.text = time_converter.toTime(countdown--);

};
```

Comment: What Titanium SDK version are you using? Do you have main thread enabled in `tiapp.xml`?

Comment: I am using 5.2.0. I do not have the main thread enabled in the tiapp.xml. Should I put it in iOS section or higher? I found an example on github, but it uses hyperloop. https://github.com/appcelerator/hyperloop-examples/blob/5c2a42fa1f8209a1cc684886408c39e792c7f408/tiapp.xml

Comment: When add **<run on main thread>**


    [ERROR] :  Script Error {[ERROR] :      column = 16; 
    [ERROR] :      line = 231;
    [ERROR] :      message = "undefined is not an object (evaluating                    'Ti.Stream.pump')";
    [ERROR] :      sourceURL = "p/app.js";
    [ERROR] :      stack = "capp.js:231:16";
    [ERROR] :

Comment: I was only asking if you had `<run-on-main-thead>` enabled because that might have caused this issue. Could you please create a JIRA ticket to report what might be a 5.2.0 regression then? Please attach a simple project that reproduces the issue. BTW, the error you run into when you enable main-thread is https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20425.

Comment: After some further testing, I think it is related to the module I have been using - TiAccurateTimer.

Answer (score 2):

`setTimeout(function_name , 0);` is the best way to run it on main thread.

For some plugins sometimes we cannot access UI objects, and have the same issue with contexts because they don't run it on main thread.

In my case i faced this issue in Touch ID functionality for which I have used **`Ti.TouchId`** module **`authenticate`** function for IOS 8.

I was not able to run **`Alloy.createController("window_Name").getView();`**
and 
Error received was `Creating [object WindowName] in a different context than the calling function.`

At the moment I don't think Titanium can fix this in plugin only .

I used **`setTimeout(function_name , 0);`** and it is working fine for me.

Comment: Please format your answers as it is hard to read at the moment.